# Regex JS: Selecting all spaces not within quotes for multiple quotes in a row

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

So I need to select all spaces not between quotes and delete them, I am using regex in Javascript notation.

For example:

```
" Test Test " ab c " Test" "Test " "Test" "T e s t"
```

becomes

```
" Test Test "abc" Test""Test ""Test""T e s t"
```

UPDATE:
I am looking for a solution that would work in the above test setting:
https://www.regextester.com/

The goal is to effectively tokenize this long sentence by these spaces not included within quotes, but I figured the answer to the above question was more concise and easier to read/answer.

All Spaces not within quotes should be highlighted in the above setting. If they are highlighted in the above setting they would be parsed as follows:

```
[" Test Test ",ab,c," Test","Test ","Test","T e s t"]
```

My attempted solution was:

```
(,|;\s|\s)+(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))(?![^\{]*\})(?![^"].*")
```

Comment: @anubhava Added attempted solution and more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for `.split`:

```bash
\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

This regex will split on spaces if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are **even number of quotes after space**.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y71UjO/1)

```js
const str = '" Test Test " ab c " Test" "Test " "Test" "T e s t"';

var arr = str.split(/\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

console.log(arr);

/* OUTPUT
[
  "\" Test Test \"",
  "ab",
  "c",
  "\" Test\"",
  "\"Test \"",
  "\"Test\"",
  "\"T e s t\""
]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "quotes or space" with "the same thing or nothing":

```js
input = `" Test Test " ab c " Test" "Test " "Test" "T e s t"`

result = input.replace(/(".*?")|( )/g, (_, $1, $2) => $1 || '')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi @gog. I just edited my question to hopefully make it a bit clearer as to what I am aiming for. I apologize for not including more detail to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

We can try a regex replacement approach with a callback function:

```js
var input = '" Test Test " ab c " Test" "Test " "Test" "T e s t"';
var output = input.replace(/".*?"|[^"]+/g, (x) => x.match(/^".*"$/) ? x : x.replace(/\s+/g, ""));
console.log(output);
```

The strategy here is to match, alternatively, either a term in double quotes, or any other content not involving a doubly quoted term.  The case of the former, we do no substitution.  In the case of the latter, we remove all whitespace characters.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen. Just edited my question above to provide more detail as to my use case to hopefully make it a bit clearer as to what I am aiming for. I apologize for not including more detail to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the following:

```
(,|;\s|\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))+(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))(?![^\{]*\})
```

First part handles selection of , ;\s and spaces and  the second half makes sure they are not in quotes. Next part handles ignoring things not encased in quotes. And then the last part handles brackets etc.

Comment: As you note this regex is way more complex than what I posted above in my answer. Did that work for you?

Comment: Yes yours worked as well for that specific task, but as for "select all spaces not between quotes" so then i could delete etc I found that this monstrosity of a solution worked well as it works for enclosed (), {}, "", etc.

Comment: See even after my comment to add clarity your question only shows double quoted text and expected output with spaces removed from quoted text. If you don't post all requirements in question you will never get any working answer. If you edit your question and show few more examples then I can certainly much simpler regex than this one.

Comment: The extra stuff is just a plus. Thats why I upvoted your answer but accepted mine. The primary thing I was asking for was something to "select all spaces not between quotes and delete them." Thats why in the update after your comment asking for clarification I wrote "All Spaces not within quotes should be highlighted in the above setting..." referencing the regextester link included. Thats why I upvoted your answer but accepted this one for the question as it works as desired in the regextester and selects all the spaces which I can then delete later. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: No doubt, it is your choice to mark any answer as accepted. However at present this answer seems to be solving some problem which is not even part of the question. Just think about a future visitor to this post after few months/years, how will that person correlate posted question and this answer?

Comment: If you can edit your answer to include selection followed by replace I would prefer to accept yours. But if you could modify your answer that would be preferable as selection followed by replacement is the intended behavior. Could you do this?

Comment: In replacement do you want me to remove double quotes e.g. `'\" Test Test \"'` to this: `' Test Test '` ?